# TF10216: Team Foundation services are currently unavailable. (user problem?)

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have some trouble getting my team foundation server to work.

If i try to access the http://:8080/services/v1.0/serverstatus.asmx with the "administrator" account everything seems fine.

But if i try to access it as some other user i get:

TF10216: Team Foundation services are currently unavailable. Try again later. If the problem persists, contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

I cant find any errors in the event logs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

By default, only the "Team Foundation Administrators" group has access to the web services, and it only contains the local admins group and the TFS service account (unless you've modified it). You can read about the group here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253077(VS.80).aspx

You may need to add other users to this group, or populate some of the other permissions groups in TFS (Project Administrators for various projects, etc).

Also, the URL in your question looks odd - it ought to have a servername section:

http://**SERVERNAME.DOMAIN.NET**:8080/services/v1.0/serverstatus.asmx